# UIView animation inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I´m developing an iOS app that has in one view a `UITableView` with two custom `UITableViewCell`. All this using a main storyboard.
Everything works pretty fine. But what I need to implement is a single fade in/fade out animation in one `UIView` from ***just one*** cell. 
Currently I´m using a this code to animate the view:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

                        self.myView.alpha = 0;

                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        self.myView.alpha = 1;

                    }];
```

In a "set content" method that I call in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` data source method of the `UITableView`.

The animations works ok. Even if a change between views the view still animating. My problem is when I reload the data from the table view or the table view scrolls up or down until the cell with the animation disappear and it has to reuse the cell to show it again, in that moment the cell is presented with no animation.

What am I missing in here? Is there a better way to implement this? How do I restart the animation after the table view reuses the cell?

I think is important to remark that according to my UI design only one cell will have the animation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you should implement one more `delegate` method of `UITableView`, which is -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

& perform your animations on the respective view of the respective cell inside it.

The below method will be called every time the cell is displayed, (also in case if it goes out of the TableView's frame and comes back to the visible area)

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //row number on which you want to animate your view
    //row number could be either 0 or 1 as you are creating two cells
    //suppose you want to animate view on cell at 0 index
    if(indexPath.row == 0) //check for the 0th index cell
    {
         // access the view which you want to animate from it's tag
         UIView *myView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:MY_VIEW_TAG];

         // apply animation on the accessed view
         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
         {
                   [myView setAlpha:0.0];
         } completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
                   [myView setAlpha:1.0];
         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, tha helped a lot, thanks!. But still not working in some other cases like `reloadData` method. Thanks to your response and also using `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method to stop the animation because it seems that also it causing problems.

Comment: In willDisplayCell: if you are animating the view for 1.2 seconds than after this duration is over animation will stop automatically, actually I didn't understand the use of tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method. I need to know the use of it, can you please elobrate a little on it, thanks.

Comment: I´m using it to remove the animation from the view because I realised that if the animation is interrupt it won't start again.

Comment: will display cell works every time, the cell is loaded can we do it once only and stop? Consider a progress bar in UITableViewCell. Just load once and then stop @SanjayMohnani

Answer (score 1):

Using `UIView` animations. Works in Swift 4.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            cell.alpha = 1
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As in **swift 4** you can use this animation

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.alpha = 0
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            cell.alpha = 1
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 1, 1, 1)
        }
    }
```