# Animate ProgressView in Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I would like to add a progressView in an CollectionViewCell. The ProgressView should be animated and runs von 1 to 0 progress in exact 10 seconds.

So now ill used "viewWithTag" for every progressView, and update my progress with:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { () -> Void in
    progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
})
```

But, ill guess it has to be much easier. When ill reload the Cell, i want to animate the progress again. So should it be easier including that function directly to my cell?

Like:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    print("prepareForReuse")
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { () -> Void in
       progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
    })
}
```

But this is not working, and should be still a problem too when scrolling. Is there a way to animate a progressView in an cell for exact 10 seconds, and (when you scroll) the progressView still not start from beginning?

Ok i am now starting my animation when ill update my cell:

```
func updateCell() {

    photos[2].comment = "dsadhjsa hdjksahdjsahfk jhasfjklha fjkhdjsk fhjksdf hjskdfh jkdshfjksdh fdhsjkfhdsjkf dsadsad dsad sad " // test Test 

    let h: Int = random() % 100;

    photos[2].height = 120 + CGFloat(h) // set custom height for test

    let path = NSIndexPath(forItem: 2, inSection: 0)

    self.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

    collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([path])

    if let progressView = view.viewWithTag(2) as? UIProgressView {

       progressView.setProgress(0, animated: false)

       UIView.animateWithDuration(4, animations: { () -> Void in
       progressView.layoutIfNeeded()
       progressView.setProgress(1, animated: true)

  })

}

}
```

This is working, but (of course) when i am scroll down my cell looses the animation. I guess it would be a better way to store the current progress value, and if the cell gets visible again, i will load it again?

Or are there other possibilities?

Comment: Add a 0.5 second delay in the animation block.

Comment: And how should that help me when the cell gets reused (so the animation starts from begin?)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
super.prepareForReuse()
print("prepareForReuse")
UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { () -> Void in
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
  progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
   }
    })
}
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks - but is not working. Ill reload my cell with a timer now every 3 seconds, first time its ok, but never anymore. And ill set it on begin to 0.     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
      self.progressView.setProgress(0, animated: false)
    }

Comment: i am reloading my cell with an timer. But my problem is that the progressbar runs on 100%, and then stays at that level. And when ill use prepareForReuse - when ill scroll, will the progressbar starts again?

Comment: So thats not a good idea - because when ill scroll, my progressView will start running from begin.

Comment: i wanna show content in each cell, and this content is updated every 10 seconds. Thats why thats not a good idea.

Comment: have you checked in willDisplayCell . here is a link which is in tableview. check if you it get any idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404586/uiview-animation-inside-uitableviewcell